# xampp ubuntu configurating map for upload

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I recently installed xampp, followed the installation. MySQL/apache. (I have same website running on windows) and now I have a map for uploading files to server. I set promission to 775, then to 777... and still I have problems uploading files. Files smaller than 100kb uploading fine, but bigger are not uploading. Searched the web, but everyone is talking about promission on map... Any idea how I can troubleshoot?

Ubuntu 11.04 desktop, Installed in VM box. (In windwos uploading works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If small uploads are OK, it's probably a PHP directive in php.ini

Have a look to upload_max_filesize, default is 2M for me. After editing, you'll have to restart Apache

Comment: You're welcome :) If this works, consider to mark it as resolved. Else I'm still around